# How to render a high-score in base.html

Tags: django

So we're writing a super simple game-app (answer questions, get points) and we want to render a high-score in the side-bar of every screen on the page.

So I understand that Django automatically (kinda) passes the authenticated user as argument (if we use render() ) but I'm not sure how to pass what basically will be:

```
top_list = User.objects.filter().order_by('-score')[:10]
```

so that we can fix a nice little top list in our base template :)

We've looked around at different questions here, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708946/how-to-get-user-value-in-base-html) for example and thought about whether the solution would be to write our own context processor?

**EDIT:**
Might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119869/how-to-send-data-to-base-html-in-django?rq=1) so should I perhaps write a  custom template tag instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use django template tags to do it..

Under `myapp/templatetags/` create a `myapp_tags.py` and `__init__.py`

In `myapp_tags.py` do the following:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_top_list():
    top_list = User.objects.filter().order_by('-score')[:10] 
    return top_list
```

And then use it in your templates like this:

```
{% load myapp_tags %}

{% get_top_list as top_list %}

{% for top_user in top_list %}
...
```

Comment: Thank you! As soon as we've learned how to make a side-bar in css/html I'll check out if the implementation works! But it sounds like a solid solution! :)